# Insert nested JSON object in a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, insert, amazon-rds

I have MySQL (v 5.7) table syntaxed as:

```
CREATE TABLE risk_summary (
    u_id BINARY(16) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    calculation_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    calculation_parameters NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
    comprehensive NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
);
```

I need to insert the data into one column (`comprehensive`) in the form of JSON. The JSON that I need to insert into the `**comprehensive**` column is this (Sample):

```
        [
            {
                "label": "5/27/20",
                "date": "05-27-2020 19:07 UTC",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "critical",
                    "count": 2
                },
                "cat3_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "high",
                    "count": 8
                },
                "cat2_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "moderate",
                    "count": 11
                },
                "cat1_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "low",
                    "count": 16
                },
                "cat0_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "unknown",
                    "count": 3
                },
                "median": 1.05
            },
            {
                "label": "Apr. 2019",
                "date": "04-27-2019 15:22 UTC",
                "cat4_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "critical",
                    "count": 4
                },
                "cat3_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "high",
                    "count": 3
                },
                "cat2_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "moderate",
                    "count": 15
                },
                "cat1_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "low",
                    "count": 12
                },
                "cat0_cnt": {
                    "stratus": "unknown",
                    "count": 0
                },
                "median": 1.25
            }
        ]
```

The `insert` for the following SQL operation that I wrote (using `AWS RDS query editor`):

```
INSERT INTO Risk_Summary VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE("6p9dbhica-56tg-471a-af27-31beb4b34bb2", "-","")),
    NOW(),
    "{a:1, b:2} ",
    "[{ "label": "5/27/20", "date": "05-27-2020 19:07 UTC", "cat4_cnt": "{ stratus: "critical", count: 2 }", "cat3_cnt": "{ stratus: "high", count: 8 }", "cat2_cnt": "{ stratus: "moderate", count: 11 }", "cat1_cnt": "{ stratus: "low", count: 16 }", "cat0_cnt": "{ stratus: "unknown", count: 3 }", "median": 1.05 }, { "label": "Apr. 2019", "date": "04-27-2019 15:22 UTC", "cat4_cnt": "{ stratus: "critical", count: 4 }", "cat3_cnt": "{ stratus: "high", count: 3 }", "cat2_cnt": "{ stratus: "moderate", count: 15 }", "cat1_cnt": "{ stratus: "low", count: 12 }", "cat0_cnt": "{ stratus: "unknown", count: 0 }", "median": 1.25 }]",
);
```

But the query editor throws an error: `Cannot find parameter: 07`.

I tried `JSON` [data-type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) as per MYSQL 5.7 docs, but that also doesn't work for me.

If anyone can help through the same, highly appreciated :)

Comment: Dont know what might cause it as of yet but we can try to fix the issues we can see. You have an issue. You cannot use double qoutes to qoute string both inner and outer. change "[{ "label":...." to '[{ "label":...'.

Comment: I updated the whole row like: `"[{ label: '5/27/20', date: '05-27-2020 19:07 UTC', cat4_cnt: "{ stratus: 'critical', count: 2 }", cat3_cnt: "{ stratus: 'high', count: 8 }", cat2_cnt: "{ stratus: 'moderate', count: 11 }", cat1_cnt: "{ stratus: 'low', count: 16 }", cat0_cnt: "{ stratus: 'unknown', count: 3 }', median: 1.05 }, { label: 'Apr. 2019', date: '04-27-2019 15:22 UTC', cat4_cnt: '{ stratus: 'critical', count: 4 }', .....]"` to which it threw new error `Cannot find parameter: 22`, not sure if that is related to `date: '04-27-2019 15:22 UTC` parameter in the string ?

Comment: Edit the question with proper formatting, do not post the code as comment.

Comment: You replace wrong symbols - you must replace outer dquotes. In ALL values.

Comment: PS. The table has 5 columns whereas your query sets 4 columns only (looks like `label` value is lost). And you provide wrong string value for UNHEX - it must contain hexadecimal digits only.

Comment: @Akina I removed the label column from the table, was a typo. And inserting into every other column work fine except for the `comprehensive`

Comment: @Akina Can you please elaborate a bit on what is meant by 'in ALL values'?

Comment: *what is meant by 'in ALL values'?* In REPLACE() arguments. In the value for `calculation_parameters` column.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=990dd1bc722b736e16cd9ee16186c016 PS. JSON is wrong - for example, in this fragment: `"cat4_cnt": "{ stratus: "critical", count: 2 }",` dquotes are placed out of object brackets wrongly.

Comment: @Akina. It worked like charm. Thanks a lot :)